# How to call the object's destructor, if its pointer's address was stored as an unsigned integer, and this is the only thing which is known?

Tags: c++, pointers, garbage-collection, set

I'm writing a garbage collection library using c++. There the object's destructors are working as finalizers, releasing object's internal data when the object's memory is being freed. Pointer addresses are stored in the set (`std::set`) as unsigned integers:

```
std::set<unsigned int> addresses;

C1* c1 = new C1();
C2* c2 = new C2();

addresses.insert(*c1);
addresses.insert(*c2); // so now pointer's addresses are stored in the set
```

when the object is needed to be released, I wanted to call the destructor:

```
std::set<unsigned int>::iterator it = addresses.begin(); // for example delete the first one
/* 1st variant */ delete *it; // not working, because "unsigned int is not a pointer type"
/* 2nd variant */ delete (void*)(*it); // frees memory, but doesn't call the destructor.
```

Is it possible in principle to call the object's destructor, if the only thing I know about it is its address which is stored as an unsigned integer?

Maybe I made a mistake in the design phase? The objects has different types, and I have to store their addresses to free the memory when necessary, but I also need to call their destructors. How can I deal with this?

Comment: 1. Your code shows that you are storing the value of `c1` and `c2`, which can't possibly work. 
2. Pointers may be larger than `unsigned int` - use `uintptr_t` instead.
3. To be able to delete an object, you need to know it's type. There are no two ways about that.

Comment: `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are two classes that are designed specifically to store an address along with the correct means of deleting it.

Comment: @SteveJessop both shared_ptr and unique_ptr are template types! So there's no difficulty if the object's type is known (it is known because templates are compile-time constructions). Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @RomanChehowsky: but you can use `void` as the template parameter. Then the type of the object is not part of the type of the smart pointer, but you can still provide a suitable deleter provided you know the real type at the point where the smart pointer is created.

Comment: @SteveJessop, wow, I didn't know about it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I'd use `void*` rather than `unsigned int`, but that doesn't help get back the information that was thrown away when a pointer with a known type was stored into a container that has no information on the type. In short, unless you store information about the type of the pointed-to object, either with a typed pointer or through some form of external information, you can't delete it.

Comment: I am collecting some metadata and save it "before" the address at which the object's data begins, so ([metadata][object]). What a pity that there is no way to do it.

Comment: @RomanChehowsky - sigh; you said "the only thing I know about it is its address". If you have more information about it then more things may be possible.

Comment: I thought that my stored size and some flags are useless. Well, I know the address, and have some metadata. Is there anything else that I can store to make possible what I've asked for?

Comment: @RomanChehowsky - sure; you need to store a pointer to a function that can destroy the stored object. You can't take the address of a destructor, so it has to be an ordinary function that simply destroys the object.

Comment: can you please show an example? How to store a destructor function as the universal type and then call it?

Comment: @RomanChehowsky - `void destroy_foo(void *ptr) { static_cast<Foo*>(ptr)->~Foo(); }` Obviously this requires one function for each type; that's how you get back the type information that the container threw away.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in principle, to call the object's destructor, if the only thing I know about it is its address which is stored as unsigned integer?

No, because you don't know the type of the object.

If all your objects were inherited from a CollectableObject base class vith a virtual destructor, then you could use `std::set<CollectableObject*> objects`.

Comment: thanks for this. I tried very hard to avoid this, but apparently I have no choice.